# Why does facebook change the link in the FB.ui send dialog?

Tags: facebook, security

I'm creating a facebook dialog here that links to an external site (not from my domain).  In the preview the link shows up correctly, but when the message is viewed in the inbox the url has been changed.

Specifically, I call this function:

```
var link = "http://someexternalsite.com/?id=xxx"
var desc = "a description"

    FB.ui(
      {
        method: 'send',
        name: 'title',
        link: link,
        picture: 'http://mysite.com/somepicture.jpg',
        description: desc
      },
      function(response) {}
    )
```

And the link changes (when viewed in your facebook inbox) to

```
http://facebook.com/someexternalsite
```

Is there some unwritten security policy somewhere?  Do I need to get permission from someexternalsite.com to link to their site?

Comment: This doesn't make sense, are you sure you're not referring to the fact that the link is to http://www.facebook.com/l.php and this redirects to the intended URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook keeps control of the links that are posted. That way if a link is to a virus or a malicious site, Facebook just needs to change their URL.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that facebook take the meta og: property.

I didn't find a way to get the link I wanted without changing the og:url.
Btw the picture is also erase by the og:image tag.

Comment: the og:url property is where your page specifies its canonical URL - if you were pointing this at an address on facebook.com that's why you had a problem, it should point to the URL for the thing you're trying to share or like

Comment: That's what I'm doing, but when you share the fb javascript sdk let you change the title, the description, the image and the link.
Only if you don't specify it, facebook take it in the og tag. This work fine on sharing, but on sending, it only take the description and the title and no matter what take the image and the link in the og tag.